# Using Discord.NET, how do i record an interaction response into a variable?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I recently stumbled across the issue that an interaction response cannot be recorded into a variable for latter handling with a typical method, `var msg  = await Context.Interaction.RespondAsync(embed: Completed.Build());` because RespondAsync is an `async Task` not giving any message type output.

I tried searching the official API as well as asking AI but haven't found any valid answer.
Also i tried

```
var msg  = await Context.Interaction.RespondAsync(embed: Completed.Build()).MethodOrProperty;
//as well as
var msg  = (await Context.Interaction.RespondAsync(embed: Completed.Build()) as AnyMessageType);
```

which didn't work for pretty obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source, you will notice that the comment has recently changed:

From:

> A task that represents an asynchronous send operation for delivering the message. The task result contains the sent message.

To:

> A task that represents an asynchronous send operation for delivering the message.

The [Pull Request](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/pull/2673) for this change says the XML documentation was a mistake and has been fixed.

It seems there is no result containing the message.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that there is `Context.Interaction.GetOriginalResponseAsync`. Hope that helps anybody with the same issue.